# HTML input text field doesn't work

Tags: html, leaflet, textfield

I am currently working on a map based on leaflet. All the input type of text doesn't work now. Like below：

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="search-input" autocomplete="off">
```

The text box is shown on the page, but not clickable or input text into it. If i remove file "leaflet.js", the text box works just fine, but all the other stuff is gone in the same time.

leaflet example:

```
var world_map =L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
});
var map = L.map('map',{
    center:[50.979, 11.322], 
    zoom:6,
    layers:world_map
});
```

Does anyone have any idea where the problem is?

Comment: Can you show us an example with leaflet.js?

Comment: @imtheman, just add an example of leaflet usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the leaflet.js [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#domevent):

```
el = document.getElementById('search-input');
L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(el);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `leaflet.js` there's probably something that made it disabled. All I can think of to fix it is to overwrite it with your own code:

```
<script> 
    document.getElementById("search-input").disabled = false
</script>
```